# How can I make LaTeX prefer to place page break between paragraphs?

Tags: environments, page-breaking, memoir

I'm typesetting fiction using the `memoir` class, and there are several "scenes" in the story that take place in a chat room.

I've created an environment that sets up the paragraphs and fonts how I want them, but there's still some awkwardness.

Minimal working example (with xelatex):

```
\documentclass[statementpaper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\defaultraggedyrightspace}
\setlength{\defaultraggedyrightspace}{1.85em}

\newlength{\prechatparindent}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{chatroom}{}{
    \raggedyright[2.5em]
    \setlength{\prechatparindent}{\parindent}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0em}
    \nonzeroparskip{}
    \ttfamily{}
}{
    \normalfont{}
    \raggedyright[\defaultraggedyrightspace]
    \setlength{\parindent}{\prechatparindent}
    \traditionalparskip{}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{It was a dark and stormy night}
\lipsum[2-6]

\begin{chatroom}

    \textbf{AOL Chat Room}\\
    \textbf{The Crash Pad – A Place to Start}
    
    \textbf{OnlineHost}\\
    ****GreenSky has entered the room.****
    
    \textbf{GreenSky}\\
    Hello everyone. I would like to discuss the ethics of war and conquest.
    Which chat room would be a good place to do that?
    
    \textbf{Blksnakexxxx}\\
    A/S/L?
    
    \textbf{SweetEzcape101}\\
    Whta a fukin nerd lol
    
    \textbf{PHaTMoNkEy}\\
    r u my social studies teacher? better get back 2 writing my essay 4 ur
    class roflmao
    
    \textbf{GreenSky}\\
    I am new to using the Internet. I just want some advice.
    
    \textbf{OOo\_KawaiiChica\_oOo}\\
    hiiiiii newbie! X3 *glomps you*
    
    \textbf{ILoveMyChevyTruck69}\\
    Type 9 if ur a woman with a pic
    
    \textbf{SailorNeptuneRox}\\
    Hey GreenSky, my friend hangs out on an IRC channel where they talk
    about stuff like that sometimes.
    
    \textbf{SailorNeptuneRox}\\
    Check out the \#philosophy channel on the Undernet server.
    
    \end{chatroom}

\section*{It was a bright and sunny day}

\lipsum[5-8]

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

Sometimes the page break will happen to fall between the handle and the first line of the chat utterance. I would especially like to avoid this. I would also like LaTeX to prefer placing pagebreaks *between* paragraphs, but this is less bad than a pagebreak immediately after the handle.

I would also like to define a new command for a "paragraph" of chat, so that I can have something like this in my source:

```
\chatline[GreenSky]{
    Hello everyone. I would like to discuss the ethics of war and conquest.
    Which chat room would be a good place to do that?
}
```

I think I can improve the pagebreak location with `\nopagebreak[4]` and `\nopagebreak[1]` but I am not sure exactly how to do it. I tried this but it didn't prevent the poorly-placed pagebreak:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\chatline}{om}{\IfValueT{#1}{\nopagebreak[4]\textbf{#1}\\}\nopagebreak[1]#2}
```

Comment: \addtolength{\pardkip}{0pt plus 1fil} will help ;-)

Comment: `\\*` is a no page break linebreak, also you don't need to reset everything at the end of your environment, the settings will revert at the end of the group automatically

Comment: Thanks, David, `\\*` does work, and in combination with adjusting the widowpenalties I have gotten the output I want.